# Calculate values difference in column based on their catageories grouped by ID

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I want to calculate the difference of values by their status which stored in another column for each ID group.

**The dataset is:**

```
# Create the dataframe
d = {'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2'], 
     'Category': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],
     'Value': ['5','9','10','11','8','13','20','25']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
```

**The dataset looks like:**

```
ID Category Value
1    A        5
1    B        9
1    C        10
1    D        11
2    A        8
2    B        13
2    C        20
2    D        25
```

For example, I want to calculate the diffence of values for category B and D for each ID. But I'm not sure how should I combine the calculation with groupby.

**The ideal dataset would be like:**

```
ID   diff(B,D)
1    2
2    12
```

Thanks anyone for answering this question!

Answer (score 1):

You can do with `groupby` and `diff` after filter with `isin`

```
df.Value=pd.to_numeric(df.Value)

yourdf=df.loc[df['Category'].isin(['B','D'])].set_index('ID').groupby(level=0)['Value'].diff().dropna()
yourdf
Out[75]: 
ID
1     2.0
2    12.0
Name: Value, dtype: float64
```

Answer (score 0):

Another way around would be to use a MultiIndex

```
df2 = df.set_index(['ID', 'Category']).unstack(-1).xs('Value', axis=1, drop_level=True)

Category  A   B   C   D
ID                     
1         5   9  10  11
2         8  13  20  25

df2 = df2.apply(pd.to_numeric)
df2['D'] - df2['B']

ID
1     2
2    12
dtype: int64
```

Answer (score -1):

you can also try below one using `pivot_table` and then treditional formula of difference:

```
d = {'ID': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2', '2', '2'], 
     'Category': ['A','B','C','D','A','B','C','D'],
     'Value': ['5','9','10','11','8','13','20','25']} 
df = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
df.Value=pd.to_numeric(df.Value)
aa = df['Category'].unique()

# using a pivot table function to define in the column and then calculating the difference
df = df.pivot_table(index=['ID'],columns='Category',values='Value')
df['diff'] = df['D'] - df['B']
df = df.drop(columns=aa,axis=0)


output:
Category    diff
ID  
1           2
2           12
```

Kindly let me know if it work for you.